# Error after calling function when clicked on a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Can someone help me why am I getting errors when I try to run my code, it happens when I call `gui_alltime_music()`.

**Error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sujals\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Sujals/PycharmProjects/ITmp3/GUI.py", line 12, in gui_alltime_music`enter code here'
    Label(guiforalltime, image=logo_all, bg='black').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
  File "C:\Users\Sujals\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Sujals\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

This is mainly happening in Line # 12

`Label(guiforalltime, image=logo_all, bg='black').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)`

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


#All time music GUI

def gui_alltime_music():
    # Main Gui

    guiforalltime = Tk()
    guiforalltime.title("All TIME MUSIC")
    guiforalltime.configure(background='black')
    # Labels

    # Logo for the GUI

    logo_all = PhotoImage(file='alltime.gif')
    Label(guiforalltime, image=logo_all, bg='black').grid(row=1,
          column=0, sticky=W)

    # Running gui forever
    guiforalltime.mainloop()


#Main Gui
gui= Tk()
gui.title("ITmp3")
gui.configure(background="Black")

# Images
logo = PhotoImage(file ='me.gif')
Label (gui, image=logo, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

#Labels
Label(gui, text="Everyone Loves Music", bg="black", fg="white", 
      font="none 12 bold").grid(row=1, column=0,sticky=W)

#Buttons
Button(gui, text="Best of All Time", command=gui_alltime_music, 
      bg="purple", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)


#run the main loop
gui.mainloop()
```

> "I wanted it to display a window with my preferred image instead it
>   gave me a random error."
>
> "I already have all the photos in my directory so that's not the
>   problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code I got the same error. The problem is you already have a Tk as a main window, opening another main window is creating the problems. So whenever there is a need for another window we use `Toplevel()`. Also there's no need for `guiforalltime.mainloop()` as there's already `gui.mainloop()` running to keep the windows open.

**Change**

`Tk()` with `Toplevel()` and also remove `guiforalltime.mainloop()` inside the function `gui_alltime_music()`.

**Complete code**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


#All time music GUI

def gui_alltime_music():
    # Main Gui

    guiforalltime = Toplevel()
    guiforalltime.title("All TIME MUSIC")
    guiforalltime.configure(background='black')
    # Labels

    # Logo for the GUI
    logo_all = PhotoImage(file='alltime.gif')
    L = Label(guiforalltime, image=logo_all, bg='black')
    L.image = logo_all      # just for reference, if the image won't show
    L.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=W)


#Main Gui
gui= Tk()
gui.title("ITmp3")
gui.configure(background="Black")

# Images
logo = PhotoImage(file ='me.gif')
Label (gui, image=logo, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

#Labels
Label(gui, text="Everyone Loves Music", bg="black", fg="white", 
      font="none 12 bold").grid(row=1, column=0,sticky=W)

#Buttons
Button(gui, text="Best of All Time", command=gui_alltime_music, 
      bg="purple", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)


#run the main loop
gui.mainloop()
```